# selenium issue:How to capture dynamic voucher number in a website

Tags: selenium

I have a website where two users (user15 and user16), user 15 creates a voucher which gets approved by user16. So in the home screen of user15 a voucher number is generated which is dynamic as shown in image below.I need to capture this voucher number generated for the one whose status is ""Processed" and then put it into the search filter of user16 homepage screen.How can i capture this dynamic voucher number ?

[voucher number image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tenf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table template looks static. It is only the rows that are getting changes so you can write an xpath like below which would directly get you the voucher name:

```
//td[text()='Processed')]/preceding-sibling::td[colnumber of VoucherNubmer]
```

Comment: yes row is getting changed and why do we need to use preceding sibling in the syntax you mentioned?

Comment: as you did not copy your Page DOM (HTML Code), i just assumed standard table format and defined the above xpath.

Comment: if possible pass me on the html code of that table, i would define the exact xpath

Comment: ok do you need the html code for complete table or just for the "processed" status row?Below is the html code for the processed row

Comment: <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="v in voudata | toArray |orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:vouFilter">
<td class="ng-binding"> 3 </td>
<td class="ng-binding"> 684E8A59 </td>
<td class="ng-binding"> 2017-04-24 </td>
<td class="ng-binding"> 2017-04-17 to 2017-04-23 </td>
<td class="ng-binding"> 1 </td>
<td class="ng-binding">10.00</td>
<td class="ng-binding">0.00</td>
<td class="ng-binding">3.00</td>
<td class="ng-binding">0.00</td>
<td class="ng-binding"> 13.00 </td>
<td class="ng-binding"> 13.00 </td>
<td class="ng-binding">
Processed

Comment: //td[contains(text(),'Processed')]/preceding-sibling::td[10]

Comment: thanks this is working but what is td[10] in the syntax?

Comment: it is the index(position) of the td tag starting from the td tag with text 'Processed'

Comment: ok but if i see there are around 12 td's , so shouldnt we be using 12 instead of 10?

Comment: it should remain same as long as your table columns are static

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following steps mentioned below:

1. First select all elements from the table within the list.
2. Then using foreach loop compare the status of the element.
3. After that if(status=="Processed") then using getText() method print the value of the vochure number.

Comment: voucher number is present in the second column , how to get the text of it even if i get the status= processed.

Comment: use element.getText() method and store the value in the string variable.